# Application limits

Tags: workflow, time

My collegue has received the below notification.  We have never received this before.  Can anyone please advise what action needs to be taken?

> Your organization has reached its hourly limit for processing workflow
>   time triggers. Processing will resume in the next hour. For
>   information on application limits, see the Salesforce online help.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour as follows:

> Enterprise Edition =500 Developer Edition =50 Professional Edition=250
>   Unlimited Edition =1,000

If an organization exceeds these limits, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and 6:00 PM.

Please check the below link for more details:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231089&language=en_US&type=1

[Hourly limit exceeded for processing workflow time triggers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123401/hourly-limit-exceeded-for-processing-workflow-time-triggers)